# Mootools 1.3 How can I have get an if statement inside an "Inject" function?

Tags: mootools, inject

I need the following if statement inside the adopt code, but its not valid if it is there. is there some way I can do the same some other way?

```
var ele = new Element('li').adopt(

    new Element('span.title', {text:row.title}),
    new Element('span.subtitle').adopt(
        // Need this to work, but its invalid where it is atm
        if(row.subtitle = 1)
        {
            new Element('img', {src:'images/subTitle.png'})
        }
    ),
    new Element('span.bold', {text:row.bold}),
);

ele.iject(...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with MooTools, but I don't see why this wouldn't work:

```
var subtitle = new Element('span.subtitle');
if (row.subtitle == 1) subtitle.adopt(new Element('img', {src:'images/subTitle.png'}));

var ele = new Element('li').adopt(
    new Element('span.title', {text:row.title}),
    subtitle,
    new Element('span.bold', {text:row.bold}),
);
```

Comment: Cheers :P should'a thought'a that

Answer (score 1):

Immediate if FTW:

```
var ele = new Element('li').adopt(

    new Element('span.title', {text:row.title}),
    new Element('span.subtitle').adopt(
        (row.subtitle == 1) ? new Element('img', {src:'images/subTitle.png'}) : null
    ),
    new Element('span.bold', {text:row.bold}),
);
```